# Generate access token using openid connect (OAuth 2.0) c#

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I'm trying to try to implement oAuth login(openid) to my app.

How can I Generating OAuth 2.0(Openid connect) Access Token with C#

[image: These are the fields i use to geneate access token in postman]

I also try to use postman auto generated code snippet for C# - RestSharp but it did not work

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand clearly what you mean but i think that you try to implement basic auth logic to your app. For this purpose, you can use IdentityServer in .NET. IdentityServer implements both OpendId and OAuth concepts. After implementing Identity Server to your app, you can authenticate/authorize by using postman.

Comment: i want to implement oAuth login to my app

Comment: You try to implement your own oAuth provider or third-party provider?

Comment: third party provider